# jQuery's .click() event stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table where the first column of each row contains several icons, each one inside an a element:

```
<a title="aaa@aaa.es" class="delete" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogDeleteUser">
    <img alt="delete" src="/recursos/imagenes/iconPapelera.png">
</a>
```

And I have a jQuery function that should trigger when that link is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.delete").click(function() {
        var userEmail = $(this).attr("title");
        loadUserDelete(userEmail);
    });
```

The fact is that it worked for some time, right until I started loading the table content with TableSorter using the Pager widget and through Ajax.

The table loads just fine but for some reason the class doesn't get recognized within that function and I don't know why.

Comment: There is an unexpected end of input error..Are you sure yo have closed `});`

Comment: Please make sure you closed the document ready function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New content added *after* your code hooking up the event runs will not magically know to re-run that code to set up handlers on the new elements. You can use delegated handling instead:

```
$("selector for the container of these").on("click", "a.delete", function() {
    var userEmail = $(this).attr("title");
    loadUserDelete(userEmail);
});
```

Now, the `click` is hooked to the container all of these links are in. jQuery will call your handler if the click passed through an `a.delete` element en route to the container whilst bubbling.

Answer (score 5):

If you register a direct event listener like that, before the content it targets is loaded, the loaded elements won't be bound to the handler. You can overcome this by using delegated events, where you bind the listener to a parent element that is already present when the event handler is registered:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'a.delete', function(){
...
}):
```

Refer [jQuery's documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 2):

it is possible that the code went trough your function before creating the object. Try attaching this to the parent instead.

```
$(document).on("click","a.delete",function() {
        var userEmail = $(this).attr("title");
        loadUserDelete(userEmail);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add click event on parent control like this:

```
$("#parentControl").on("click", "a.delete", function() {
    var userEmail = $(this).attr("title");
    loadUserDelete(userEmail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an unexpected end of input error..Are you sure yo have closed `$(document).ready` function

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.delete").click(function() {
            var userEmail = $(this).attr("title");
            loadUserDelete(userEmail);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Didnt catch that. Although that is probably just a copy paste error but isnt really happening in his code (would have thrown an error) +1 to you for spotting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same situation but realized after  going through basics that the context of "this" is always changing . So if you want to use "this", first store it in a variable and then use that variable as selector rather using "this" in selector

```
var that = $(this);

that.click(function() {
  ...
});
```